# How to proxy /grafana with nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, grafana

I've setup and started default grafana and it works as expected on http://localhost:3000.  I'm trying to proxy it with nginx where I have ssl installed.  I'm trying to have it respond to https://localhost/grafana but it just serves the following:

```
{{alert.title}}
```

I have this in my nginx server block:

```
location /grafana {
     proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

Answer (score 32):

It seems nginx supports rewriting the requests to the proxied server so updating the config to this made it work:

```
location /grafana {
     proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000;
     rewrite  ^/grafana/(.*)  /$1 break;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

My grafana.ini also has an updated root:

```
[server]
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Note that due to the static assets both the nginx rewrite and the root_url config are needed, but otherwise it does the trick with Grafana 2.2.

Comment: Also, if you have basic http auth in front of nginx before it hits grafana, make sure you override the `Authorization` header by including `proxy_set_header Authorization "";` in your proxy location block, otherwise Grafana will insist in reusing these credentials for data source connections.

Comment: The rewrite rule is essential to make it work. This should really be added to the Grafana documentation at http://docs.grafana.org/installation/behind_proxy/

Comment: @dasup No, the rewrite rule is not required (at least not in grafana 4.6). You need to set `proxy_pass` to include a URI such as `/`, otherwise the request is passed through as is (see also https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/ for the explanation). So the config should be `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;` which is exactly what the grafana docs state.

Answer (score 11):

Adding on to @AXE-Labs answer, you don't need to rewrite the URL.

```
nginx.conf

location /grafana/ {
     proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000/;
     proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}

grafana.ini update root:

[server]
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/
```

Notice the additional / in the location block, that makes all the difference.

If you want to see the entire file, please visit https://gist.github.com/mvadu/5fbb7f5676ce31f2b1e6 where I have rever proxy setup for Infludb as well as grafana.

Comment: Yes, the difference is explained here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Note that trailing slash in `http://localhost:3000/;` also important.

Comment: And in `%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/` - all locations should have trailing slash.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem when using nginx and grafana on docker, in two different containers. Passed the following options to docker-compose on grafana service, following http://docs.grafana.org/installation/behind_proxy/#nginx-configuration-with-sub-path:

```
- GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=foo.bar.com
- GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:/grafana
```

But it didn't work, and my browser's console shows: `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`.

So, to fix it, I added the following line to my nginx config:

```
location /grafana/ {
  proxy_pass http://monitoring_grafana:3000/;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0; # THIS MADE THE TRICK!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a bit with all the answers here. For completeness and documentation for myself a full example which worked in my case.

`/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`:

```
... DEFAULT CONFIGURATION

#################################### Server ################################

... DEFAULT CONFIGURATION

root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/

... DEFAULT CONFIGURATION
```

`nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        #

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        ... DEFAULT SETTINGS ...

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        # note that I am not using sites-enabled:
        # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I put the NGINX configuration for grafana into a separate `grafana.conf` located in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

  root /var/www/<my.hostname.xy>/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name <my.hostname.xy>;

  location /grafana/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

`root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana`

causes proxy errors for some API calls. I find:

```
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:/grafana
```

Answer (score 0):

For Nginx `default-ssl.conf`

```
 location /login {
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
 }
```

and also you have to change `grafana.ini` configuration.

```
[server]
domain = serverdomain.com
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/
serve_from_sub_path = true
```